# TypeError: color must be int or tuple (PIL)

Tags: image, python-imaging-library

```
caption_area = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height + (height//5)), "white")
caption_area.paste(img, (5, 5, (width+5), (height+5)))
caption_area.show()
```

How do i fix this? I've looked at some other posts with similar issues but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colour that you specified is a string (`"white"`), but `Image.new` needs the colour information as an integer or a tuple. The RGBA value of white as a tuple is `(255, 255, 255, 1)` so it'd look something like this:

```py
caption_area = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height + (height//5)), (255, 255, 255, 1))
...
```

Look up "RGB colour codes" for other colours.

Comment: I am using PIL 8.1.1. In it, it is perfectly fine to specify the string `'white'` for your color, also for RGBA images.